# Can GRASS compute the line graph representation of an input graph?

Tags: grass-gis, network, graph

I'm interested in computing a line graph for an input graph, preferably in GRASS since I'll be using other [GRASS network analysis tools](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_network_analysis) afterwards. I couldn't find any reference to line graphs in the GRASS docs. Is there a different term I should be using in my search or a hidden function that would create such a graph?

For context:

> the line graph of an undirected graph G is another graph L(G) that represents the adjacencies between edges of G.
>
> [image]
>
> Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

Comment: This question is probably better posted in the grass-dev mailing list...

Comment: Thanks @markusN, done http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Can-GRASS-compute-the-line-graph-representation-of-an-input-graph-td5208721.html

Comment: The only reference I found within GRASS is the [d.linegraph](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/d.linegraph.html) function, although the input must be numerical data. I know it's not much help but atleast we know there's something in GRASS that's related to line graphs :)

Comment: Have I understood this correctly? You are looking for something like the opposite of PostGIS pgr_createTopology, where you already have the vertices but want instead to create the links described in terms of the two vertex ids? Could you parse a PostGIS vertex table to generate the network you're looking for?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, vertices in the line graph can be identified by the two vertices in the input graph. The edges in the line graph represent the adjacencies between edges in the input graph. Maybe it would work with PostGIS as you describe, but if I have to implement something from scratch that wouldn't be my first choice.

Answer (score 3):

If Python is okay, then there are some good Python modules that know about line graphs.  [One example is NetworkX](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/) (which I installed with simply `sudo pip install networkx`).

This is not a perfect answer since you need to write some glue code.  First you would convert your input into [NetworkX graph objects](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/classes.graph.html):

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node( ... )
G.add_edge( ... )
```

Then you'd call the [`line_graph` function](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html) get NetworkX to compute the line graph:

```
H = nx.line_graph(G)
```

And finally you would convert the result back to something useful by iterating over `H.edges()` and `H.nodes()`.