# Getting dual graph from QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, centroids

I have a .shp file, and I need to get the dual graph from this file (that is to say, each polygon centroid should become a vertex, and two vertices are linked if their associated polygons are adjacent).

I managed to get the centroids from the polygons of my file.

How can I add lines between the vertices that should indeed be connected?

Comment: Are you looking for an out of the box tool in QGIS or a script?

Comment: At this point, every solution is a good solution to me.

Comment: I can totally understand that however, an out of the box tool in QGIS may not be available. If you want a script, you will have to at the very least show an attempt of creating a script that can be helped with.

Comment: What form do you want the lines? As a set of line features with little link back to the original polygons?

Comment: Related to [Can GRASS compute the line graph representation of an input graph?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146713/can-grass-compute-the-line-graph-representation-of-an-input-graph)

Comment: Try the tool "join by lines (hub lines)," which creates a line layer connecting points in one layer with points in another layer, based on a common field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Python only  (versions 2.7.x and 3.x) without QGIS:

[image]

1) With [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html),  [shapely](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)  and   [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import MuliPolygon, LineString, mapping
Multi = MultiPolygon([shape(poly['geometry']) for poly in fiona.open("polygons.shp")])
# creation of the dual graph shapefile
import itertools
# schema of the dual graph shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('dual_graph.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
   for poly1,poly2 in  itertools.combinations(Multi, 2):
       if poly1.touches(poly2):
           e.write({'geometry':mapping(LineString([poly1.centroid, poly2.centroid])), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

[image]

2) with [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/),[shapely](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)  and   [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd 
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("polygons.shp")
geoms = polygon['geometry'].tolist()
dual = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries([LineString([poly1.centroid, poly2.centroid]) for poly1,poly2 in  itertools.combinations(geoms, 2) if poly1.touches(poly2)]),columns=['geometry'])
dual.to_file("dual_graph2.shp")
```

3) I suppose you can do the same thing with PyQgis  and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (Python 2.7 for 2.x versions and 3.x for 3.x versions)

Comment: The first code works fine! I might just add that it should be "as e:" instead of "as e::", and that in my case (I didn't want edges between polygons sharing only one point) I added the condition " (poly1.intersection(poly2)).geom_type!="Point" " to the if loop.